# BlackRaccoon and WhiteRaccon server timeout error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, uploading, blackraccoon

I have use White Raccoon and Black Raccoon both to upload zip file on FTP server.
In White Raccoon I was not able to upload zip file, I always get serverTimeout error. So I tried to upload normal xml file with white raccoon, File is uploaded without any data(0 byte size). Here is the code

```
-(void)upload:(NSData*)data{
   
//the upload request needs the input data to be NSData
NSData * ourImageData = data;

//we create the upload request
//we don't autorelease the object so that it will be around when the callback gets called
//this is not a good practice, in real life development you should use a retain property to store a reference to the request
WRRequestUpload * uploadImage = [[WRRequestUpload alloc] init];
uploadImage.delegate = self;

//for anonymous login just leave the username and password nil
uploadImage.hostname = @"hostname";
uploadImage.username = @"username";
uploadImage.password = @"password";

//we set our data
uploadImage.sentData = ourImageData;

//the path needs to be absolute to the FTP root folder.
//full URL would be ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/space.jpg
uploadImage.path = @"huge_test.zip";

//we start the request
[uploadImage start];
}
```

I am using this https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon

-As WhiteRaccoon is not working for me I have tried BlackRaccoon but it is not helping me to even upload a normal xml file, it just give me "Stream timed out with no response from server" error.

here is the code

```
- (IBAction) uploadFile :(NSData *)datas{

self.uploadData = [NSData dataWithData:datas];

 //Here I am just Checking that DATA come from another method is proper or not. I got All thedata which I have passed from method
    NSString  *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test12121.xml"];
    // Write the data to file
[datas writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    self.uploadFile = [[BRRequestUpload alloc] initWithDelegate: self];

//----- for anonymous login just leave the username and password nil
self.uploadFile.path = @"/test.xml";
self.uploadFile.hostname = @"hostname";
self.uploadFile.username = @"username";
self.uploadFile.password = @"password";
//we start the request
[self.uploadFile start];

}

- (long) requestDataSendSize: (BRRequestUpload *) request{

 //----- user returns the total size of data to send. Used ONLY for percentComplete
 return [self.uploadData length];

}

 - (NSData *) requestDataToSend: (BRRequestUpload *) request{

 //----- returns data object or nil when complete
 //----- basically, first time we return the pointer to the NSData.
 //----- and BR will upload the data.
 //----- Second time we return nil which means no more data to send
 NSData *temp = self.uploadData;   // this is a shallow copy of the pointer

 self.uploadData = nil;            // next time around, return nil...

 return temp;

 }

  -(void) requestFailed:(BRRequest *) request{

  if (request == uploadFile)
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", request.error.message);
    
    uploadFile = nil;
 }
   NSLog(@"%@", request.error.message);
  }

  -(BOOL) shouldOverwriteFileWithRequest: (BRRequest *) request
   {
  //----- set this as appropriate if you want the file to be overwritten
  if (request == uploadFile)
  {
    //----- if uploading a file, we set it to YES
    return YES;
  }

   //----- anything else (directories, etc) we set to NO
   return NO;
  }

  - (void) percentCompleted: (BRRequest *) request
    {
   NSLog(@"%f completed...", request.percentCompleted);
  }

  -(void) requestCompleted: (BRRequest *) request
  {
  //----- handle Create Directory
  if (request == uploadFile)
  {
    NSLog(@"%@ completed!", request);
    uploadFile = nil;
 }

 }
```

I am using https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon.

I have even changed the timeout limit upto 60 but its not working for me. Please anyone can help me?Anyone knows another way to upload zip file to FTP server, then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've also tried to establish a connection by using both of these libraries and it took me about a couple of hours and it still did not work! Then I've realized that the server only supports SFTP (secured FTP) which is not a feature in any of *Raccoon libraries

Comment: I have tried [SimpleFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) and its working for me.

Comment: are you fixed timeout issue or server not response issue ?

Comment: Hello @NSP can you please share your working code to upload a file